# Stop C# Multi-Threaded Sql calls from using same SPID

Tags: sql, sqlconnection, spid

Background, we have a local service running our sql 2008 server that imports roughly 1600 small csv files per night.  Yesterday around 11:30 pm it was running flawlessly, pushing 5-10 files per minute, but upon inspection this morning I noticed there were still over 400 files in the queue.

We push the files up in batches of 15 (15 separate threads in service) and 99% of the time have no issues.  This morning though I noticed that there were 15 files marked as loading and only one active SPID.  After checking profiler and running the service as a console app I realized that for some reason SQL has decided to mesh all calls into the same SPID.

There was no update or maintenance done last night, it was a normal execution with 0 errors reported.

Does anyone know what would cause SQL to all of the sudden package all of these calls into a single SPID?

The service pushing the files up has not been modified for over 18 months so I'm fairly certain it's something on the SQL side.

We are an SaaS company so I can't bounce the sql service until 2-3am tonight but am planning to do so.

Comment: You might improve your question title to be an actual question, rather than just a phrase.  To answer your question, it's likely that the connection pool only gave you one connection.  This might have been due to an update or something similar.

Comment: I have "Pooling=false" set in my connection string, still experiencing the same issue.  

I can watch the profiler and see all of the threads calling to the same SPID, is there a different way to block this?